# A weird Calculus of Variations problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I became stuck with the following Calculus of Variations problem. The problem is related with something called as the "Nadaraya-Watson" model in statistics. We have $N$ inputs ${x_n}$ and each of these inputs perturbed with a noise variable $\xi$. For each input $x_n$ we have a target variable $t_n$. $\xi$ comes from a probability distribution $\nu(\xi)$. Now the following sum-of-squares error is defined:

$$E = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int{(y(x_n + \xi) - t_n})^2\nu(\xi)d\xi \tag{1}$$

The aim is to find the function $y(x)$ which minimizes this error. My approach was to calculate the Gateaux variation $\dfrac{dE[y(x) + \epsilon \eta(x)]}{d \epsilon}|_{\epsilon = 0}$ and to find a $y(x)$ which makes the variation $0$ for all $\eta(x)$.

I calculate the variation as: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int{(y(x_n + \xi) - t_n})\nu(\xi)\eta(x_n + \xi)d\xi \tag{2}$$
which looks correct according to the solution set.

But I am completely clueless how to find a $y(x)$ which makes this variation $0$ for each possible $\eta(x)$!

The answer is supposed to be:

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}t_nh(x-x_n) \tag{3}$$

Where $h(x-x_n)$ is defined as:

$$h(x-x_n) = \dfrac{\nu(x - x_n)}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\nu(x - x_n)} \tag{4}$$

But this $y(x)$ does *NOT* even make the variation in $(2)$ zero for any $\eta(x)$!

Am I missing something? I need help of any kind...

Comment: It might help to substitute $x=x_n+\xi$, and thus write $(2)$ as
$$\begin{multline}
\sum_{n=1}^N\int\big(y(x)-t_n\big)\nu(x-x_n)\eta(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
=\int\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\big(y(x)-t_n\big)\nu(x-x_n)\right)\eta(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
=\int\left(y(x)\sum_{n=1}^N\nu(x-x_n)-\sum_{n=1}^Nt_n\nu(x-x_n)\right)\eta(x) \,\mathrm dx
\end{multline}$$
and then you can maybe see why $y(x)=\sum_{n=1}^Nt_n\nu(x-x_n)/\sum_{n=1}^N\nu(x-x_n)$.

Comment: When we transform $x=x_n + \xi$ then aren't the $x$ variables in the $N$ distinct integrals are different from each other? How is this substitution justified?

Comment: Well, we do a different substitution for each integral. Afterwards we can add them up because $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int g(y)\,\mathrm dy=\int\big(f(x)+g(x)\big)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: It is $\int f(x)dx + \int g(y)dy = \int (f(x)+g(x)) dx$ since at  $\int g(y) dy$ determines the same value given the function $g(.)$ and the integration bounds, independent from what we call the variable it operates on, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I think your expression (2) is off by a factor of 2 relative to the actual variation, but being a constant factor, that is irrelevant.

Since (2) must be zero for all $\eta(x)$, in particular, it is zero for 
$$
\eta(x) = \delta(x-u)$$ for any given $u$.  And in fact, since (2) is linear in $\eta$, if we find a $y(x)$ that causes (2) to vanish for
$
\eta(x) = \delta(x-u)$ for all values of $u$, then we can integrate to get any arbitrary $\eta(x)$.

When you plug $\eta(x) = \delta(x-u)$ into (2) you get
$$
\sum_n(y(u)-t_n)\nu(u-x_n) = 0 \\
\sum_n y(u) \nu(u-x_n) = \sum_n t_n(u-x_n)
$$
I used $u$ earlier to avoid confusion with the variable $x$, but at this point we can replace $u$ by $x$ to get
$$
\sum_n y(x) \nu(x-x_n) = \sum_n t_n(x-x_n) $$
from which it is easy to see that the purported solution works, and not that much harder to find the solution without being told what it will be.

Comment: But in this solution, we only assume that $\eta(x)$ to be a Dirac function? How does this generalize to arbitrary functions?